# Display Album and Artist in listview with LoaderManager and CursorLoader

Tags: android, android-listfragment, android-music-player, android-cursorloader

I have a `ListFragment` whose list should diplay the Albums of the device and the associated artist using `MediaStore`. Each row has thus two `TextViews`.
I'm using `LoaderManager` and `CursorLoader` to fill the list up, with a custom CursorAdapter in order to bind the `TextViews` of the row to the data.

**ListFragment Code :**

```
public class AlbumsFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

AlbumsAdapter mAdapter;

        @Override
           public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.albums_fragment_layout, container, false);
           return myFragmentView;
         }


        @Override
          public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

                    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
                    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);                               
        }


static final String[] ALBUM_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = { MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST}; 



        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {      
            String select = null;  
            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,ALBUM_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null, null);  
        }  



        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {  
            mAdapter.swapCursor(data);  
        }  



        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {  
            mAdapter.swapCursor(null);  
        }  
    }
```

**AlbumsAdapter (Custom CursorAdapter) Code :**

```
public class AlbumsAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

     public AlbumsAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        TextView albumTitle =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.albumTextView);
        albumTitle.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM)));

        TextView artistName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.artistTextView);
        artistName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST)));

    }


    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.albums_row,parent,false); 
        return view;
    }
```

For the moment, when I display this ListFragment, I have a java.lang.NullPointerException, here is the logCat :

```
 06-14 09:39:23.109: W/dalvikvm(8632): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c2d1f8)
06-14 09:39:23.109: E/AndroidRuntime(8632): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 09:39:23.109: E/AndroidRuntime(8632): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 09:39:23.109: E/AndroidRuntime(8632):     at com.music.pod.AlbumsFragment.onLoadFinished(AlbumsFragment.java:61)
06-14 09:39:23.109: E/AndroidRuntime(8632):     at com.music.pod.AlbumsFragment.onLoadFinished(AlbumsFragment.java:1)
06-14 09:39:23.109: E/AndroidRuntime(8632):     at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:438)
06-14 09:39:23.109: E/AndroidRuntime(8632):     at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:406)
06-14 09:39:23.109: E/AndroidRuntime(8632):     at android.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:125)
06-14 09:39:23.109: E/AndroidRuntime(8632):     at android.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:88)
06-14 09:39:23.109: E/AndroidRuntime(8632):     at android.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:42)
06-14 09:39:23.109: E/AndroidRuntime(8632):     at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:236)
06-14 09:39:23.109: E/AndroidRuntime(8632):     at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:76)
06-14 09:39:23.109: E/AndroidRuntime(8632):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
06-14 09:39:23.109: E/AndroidRuntime(8632):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
06-14 09:39:23.109: E/AndroidRuntime(8632):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
06-14 09:39:23.109: E/AndroidRuntime(8632):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-14 09:39:23.109: E/AndroidRuntime(8632):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-14 09:39:23.109: E/AndroidRuntime(8632):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
06-14 09:39:23.109: E/AndroidRuntime(8632):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 09:39:23.109: E/AndroidRuntime(8632):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-14 09:39:23.109: E/AndroidRuntime(8632):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
06-14 09:39:23.109: E/AndroidRuntime(8632):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
06-14 09:39:23.109: E/AndroidRuntime(8632):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Could you please help me to correct my code in order to have the album and the associated artist displayed into the listview ?

**Problem Solved :**

For anyone trying to fill up a custom listview with Album,Artist,etc... with the technique LoaderManager/CursorLoader you should :

1) Create your own Custom CursorAdapter which binds TextViews of your row to Cursor's data(see my Custom CursorAdapter above)

2) Then, in your fragment here's what to do :

```
public class AlbumsFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

AlbumsAdapter mAdapter;

        @Override
           public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.albums_fragment_layout, container, false);
           return myFragmentView;
         }


        @Override
          public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

                    mAdapter = new AlbumsAdapter(getActivity(), null);
                    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
                    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);                               
        }


static final String[] ALBUM_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = { MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST};  



        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {      
            String select = null;  
            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,ALBUM_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null, null);  
        }  



        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {  
            mAdapter.swapCursor(data);  
        }  



        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {  
            mAdapter.swapCursor(null);  
        }  
    }
```

And that's it !!! I don't know why nobody has ever procured a very simple example like this about how to use LoaderManager,CursorLoader and Custom adapter in order to fill a custom listview. Anyway, I hope this will help beginners like me in the future.

Comment: When you have an exception(`NullPointerException` or whatever exception) you should always show the line where that exception is thrown.

Comment: @Luksprog : Thanks for the precision, I've updated my post. The exception seems to be at line 61 where there's `mAdapter.swapCursor(data);`. Maybe there's something wrong the way I query the `MediaStore` so the `data` are empty causing this exception ?

Comment: Hey @Jecimi I have a few questions if you don't mind. I too am trying to make  a CursorAdapter with a LoaderManager and CursorLoader. Except I am getting a cursor from a database. I am also not using a ListFragment, but just a regular list. So that means my list is in an activity with another view, a GridView actually. How can I set this up to use LoaderManager and CursorLoader without having to change my current layout?

Comment: @Andy: If you have only one `ListView` in your layout, the other Views being of other kind, I think the simplest is to convert your `Activity` to a `ListActivity`. Even if it is a `ListActivity`, it doesn't mean that you have to have compulsory only one `ListView`, it just mean that your activity contain one `ListView`.Look at my `ListFragment` above, I do inflate it with my XML `albums_fragment_layout.xml` which doesn't contain only one `ListView` but other views. You just have to set `android:id="@id/android:list` to your `ListView`, then just use your `ListActivity` like a `ListFragment`.

Comment: I searched for hours and this helped me out tremendously... so clear and concise!  Along with sections 1-3 in this tutorial it made implementation a breeze.  http://mobile.tutsplus.com/series/android-fundamentals/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `mAdapter` is `null`(I don't see where you initialized it, if you initialized it) and when you try to swap the cursor it throws that exception.

if you didn't initialized that `AlbumAdapter` reference then you should do it before you set the adapter:

```
mAdapter = new AlbumsAdapter(getActivity(), null);
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Two things were missing : I forgot to initialize the custom Adapter as you said and I forgot to put `MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID` in my projection.